# Comunicacion ApiRest con angular

Tags: angular, api, spring, rest, http

estoy desarrollando un proyecto donde tengo un api rest generada con spring y de fronted tengo angular actualmente no tengo ningun problema con respecto a consumirlas lo hago de esta manera :

```
ListarTodos() {
return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/usuario');}
```

el detalle es que la respuesta de mi api rest es algo similar a esto

```
{
"persona": {
    "nombreCompleto": "ninguno2 ninguno2 ninguno2",
    "fechaIngreso": "2019-04-10",
    "randomAccess": "8137",
    "foto": null,
    "id": 13
},
"error": false}
```

como pueden observar doy un mensaje y un resultado y para consumirlo lo hago de manera de

```
this._ps.ListarTodos().subscribe( (res: any[]) =>{
this.listadoPersonas = res.personas;
})
```

el detalle esta en que me marca un error de esta manera constante en la consola

```
'personas' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
Property 'persona' does not exist on type 'Object'
```

alguna idea para el correcto manejo de los servicios rest ? o como solventar este problema ?

Comment: Hola, ¿que tal si en vez de `res: any[]` haces solo `res: any`?

Comment: me funciono perfectamente ya no me sale el error o el mensaje .. me podrias explicar por que pasaria esto .. pienso en hacer una interface para este tipo de cosas pero  como mi estructura es

{
error::{}
data:{}
}

no se como al final podria hacer para que data explicitamente sea mi interface

Comment: Creo que si bien tu intención es recibir ***cualquier*** (`any`) tipo de datos, estás restringiendo `response` a que sea un Objeto de tipo `Array`, cuyos elementos pueden ser `any`. Imagino que más adelante en tu código intentas acceder a la propiedad `persona` que viene en tu `response` (de acuerdo a lo que indicas que devuelve tu API) y es por ello que al transpilar te da el error por consola, ya que un tipo `Array` no posee ninguna propiedad llamada `persona`. En cambio si asignas el tipo `any`, estás asignando a `response` que contenga cualquier tipo de dato de Javascript. Saludos

Comment: Como bien te responde @PabloLozano, así podrías crear la Interfaz, sin embargo debes aclarar en tu pregunta lo que te plantean en la respuesta, ya que el método lo llamas `ListarTodos()` y además deseas almacenar el `response` en `listadoPersonas`, lo cual se puede interpretar como que vas a recibir varios datos del tipo de tu Interface. Por otro lado, en tu mensaje de error se aprecia claramente que tratas de acceder a `personas` en plural, revisa bien lo que estás haciendo y aclara la lógica de tu aplicación. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás esperando un objeto con la estructura

```
{
  "persona": {
    "nombreCompleto": "ninguno2 ninguno2 ninguno2",
    "fechaIngreso": "2019-04-10",
    "randomAccess": "8137",
    "foto": null,
    "id": 13
  },
  "error": false
}
```

Así que podrías crear una interfaz que la cubriese:

```
interface Persona {
  nombreCompleto: string;
  fechaIngreso: string;
  randomAccess: string;
  foto: any;
  id : number;
};
interface PersonaResponse {
  persona : Persona;
  error: boolean;
}
```

Pero yo además tendría cuidado con el nombre de los métodos: si la respuesta es un objeto (una única persona), llamar al método `listarTodo` o a la propiedad donde lo guardas `listadoPersonas`te va a provocar muchos malentendidos.

El código podría quedarte así:

```
obtenerUsuario : Observable<Persona> {
  return this.http.get<Persona>('http://localhost:8080/api/usuario')
      .pipe(map((resp: PersonaResponse) => resp.persona));
}
```

Comment: se puede usar 2 interfaces en el mismo archivo ? o tendria que generar 2 archivos para cada una de las interfaces y muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Typescript, a diferencia de Java, permite crear todo lo que quieras en el mismo archivo, puedes exportar varias cosas desde el mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Desde el backend estas devolviendo un objeto 
`{ persona: ...}`

Y en angular estas esperando una lista `any[]`

O desde el Backend devuelves una lista, o desde angular asigna el tipo  `any` a la respuesta esperada.